# Container instance IAM role vs Task execution role

Tags: amazon-web-services, containers, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs

What is the difference between ECS's Container instance IAM role and Task execution role ( I know task role concept but confused between Container instance IAM role and Task execution ). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Container Instance IAM Role: The role assigned to the EC2 instance that your ECS tasks will be deployed to. This role is not used if you are deploying to Fargate. The [description of this role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/security-iam-awsmanpol.html) is:

  > Amazon ECS attaches this policy to a service role that allows Amazon ECS to
  > perform actions on your behalf against Amazon EC2 instances or external
  > instances.

  This role is used by the EC2 instances to register/join the ECS cluster.
- Task execution role: Used by the ECS service to do things like pull the image from ECR and send container logs to CloudWatch.
- Task role: This role is optional. It is the role your application code running in the ECS task container can assume to make AWS API calls.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now it is cleared to me.